# Linq over jObject.Parse - working for console app but not for WebApi project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, console-application, json.net

I'm using Json.Net to parse json returned from an api.

I have a console application, and a WebApi application, that are doing the exact same routine:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

var sections = jObject
    .Values()
    .Select(x => x.Path)
    .ToList();
```

In the console application, this works fine, and `sections` is as expected.

When the same code is executed in my WebApi controller, the following exception is thrown:

> Method not found: 'System.String Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.get_Path()'.

The value of `json` is identical in both cases!

**EDIT**

The method that parses and generates my 'sections' is actually in a separate assembly.

- Class library has reference to Newtonsoft.Json v 4.5.0.0
- WebApi project has reference to Newtonsoft.Json v 4.5.0.0
- Console application doesn't have a reference to Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Sounds like the version of your `Newtonsoft.Json` assembly differs in your projects. Check this please.

Comment: @user2674389 see my edit, both using same version (I should of included that in original post!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you are using the same version between the two projects?  The `Path` property was added to `JToken` in [Json.NET 5.0 release 1](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/104679).  If you are using version 4.5.x in one of your projects, then this property won't be available.  Note that all versions of Json.NET since 4.5 have an *assembly version* of 4.5.0.0, including 5.0.x releases.  The assembly version is what is displayed in the Properties window in Visual Studio.  So, if you're looking at that, you're probably using incorrect information.  To determine which version you are really using, you need to find the Newtonsoft.Json.dll that is being referenced by each project and check its properties.  It should be something like `5.0.8.16617`, for example, if you're on the latest.

If you are using NuGet, you can also see the installed version from there.  For each project, open the package manager UI.  In the left pane, click on "Installed packages".  In the center pane, click on Json.Net.  The installed version should then be visible in the right pane, e.g. 5.0.8.  If you need to update, you can also do this easily in NuGet.  Just click "Updates" in the left pane, again select Json.Net in the center pane, then click the Update button.  Keep in mind that each project has its own separate list of installed NuGet packages, so if you update a package in one project, that does not automatically update the other projects in the same solution.  You'll need to check each project separately.

Comment: I will check this tomorrow... am using Nuget (not sure if that will have any effect?)

Comment: Using NuGet is good.  It is very easy to see what version you're on and to update to the latest version if necessary.  I've updated my answer with more info.

Comment: It was a rogue reference, like you suspected. Was actually in a project not referenced by any of the projects in question. Updating to 5.0.8 across the solution (and removing any notion of 4.x from the packages folder) and rebuilding, fixed the issue. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to fix it.